# command line parser can not handle blank space when call python in sh

Tags: python, shell, command-line

```
a.py:
for arg in sys.argv:
    print arg

b.sh:
python a.py $*
```

situation 1:

```
python a.py "123 456"
```

get:

123 456

situation 2:

```
/bin/sh b.sh "123 456"
```

get:

123

456

It seems "123 456" will pares in two args,how can i modify b.sh, make a.py can treat "123 456" as one arg.

Comment: Look into module argparse . It provides a lot of the leg work for parsing arguments, and will auto generate help file entries etc.,

Comment: Read [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), again and again and again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need quotes:

```
python a.py "$*"
```

Also, if you use `"$@"` instead of `"$*"` it will expand to a multiple arguments.

Comment: It not work，"$*" will take all args to be on,such as:/bin/sh b.sh  a b c "123 456", it will out put "a b c 123 456", which i want is a \n b \n c \n 123 456 \n

Answer (score 0):

Argparse sample related to my comment. Greatly simplifies legwork required

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test ')
parser.add_argument('first',help="The First argument", type=str)
parser.add_argument('second',help="the second argument",type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()
```